# Convert datetime and offset in isoDate in moment.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

In the api response I am getting Date, Time and Offset in three columns. I want to get ISOdate but date and time values should not change.

```
const date="2019-04-15"
const time = "13:45"
const offset = 1 // It can be minus also -4 or -5
```

Output should be "2019-04-15T13:45:00+01:00" // Here you can see date, time and offset are same

If for same datetime offset is -4 then output should be "2019-04-15T13:45:00-04:00".

I am using this code to achieve that:

```
moment(date+'T'+time).utcOffset(offset).format();
```

But I am getting "2019-04-15T12:45:00+01:00" as it is adjusting time by offset value, which I do not require.

Comment: Try adding `true` as a second parameter to `utcOffset()` function. (https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/09-utc-offset/)

Comment: @JeremyHarris that seeems to do the trick

Comment: Added as an answer, glad it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/09-utc-offset/), in the `utcOffset()` you can use `true` as a second parameter to offset relative to a local time versus a universal time:

> Passing true will keep the same local time, but at the expense of choosing a different point in Universal Time.

Usage of this depends on how your original time is stored. If it is UTC, and calculated offset is relative to UTC, then it is not needed. But in the event the offset is relative to local server time, then you can use this additional parameter to maintain the expected relative value.